# String concatenation modifies double number when '|' is included

Tags: c#, .net

I cannot understand why this code is behaving like this. I have to return a string on a specific format. It looks like when I include the "|" character on the string, the numbers that come after it get modified.

Why would this happen? Is "|" somehow converting the double values again?

```
static int Main(string[] args) {
  .........

  connectionString = connectionString.Replace("'master'", databaseName);
  var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
      connection.Open();
    }

  watch.Stop();

  string spentTimeString = String.Format("{0:0.##}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f);

  string msg = $"Connection Time " + spentTimeString + "s.";
  string perfData = "'connection_time'=" + String.Format("{0:0.##}", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f);
  string result = Ok(msg, perfData);

  ......
}


public static string Ok(string message, string perfData)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Msg: {message}");
    Console.WriteLine($"PerfData: {perfData}");
    string result = string.Concat("OK: ", message, "|", perfData);
    Console.WriteLine($"Result: {result}");
    return result;
}
```

Here is the Console output that I see:
Msg: Connection Time **0.42**s.
PerfData: 'connection_time'=**0.42**
Result: OK: Connection Time 0.42s.|'connection_time'=**0.41999**

You can clearly see how 0.42 get's converted to 0.41999 after the concatenation takes place. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please show the actual code you're using to call the method. Passing in the strings you mentioned above does not reproduce the issue: `Ok("Connection Time 0.42s.", "'connection_time'=0.42");` The issue is most likely the code that's generating the string arguments.

Comment: I don't think this can happen with the code shown, where the numbers have already been baked into `string` values; do you have example code that actually shows the problem reported, including test values? I suspect it will need to have some `float`, `double` or `decimal` values in the example code to show the problem.

Comment: Hello guys, the post has been updated. I'm basically doing a control to measure the DB connection time. There are no multiple threads working.

Comment: That cannot possibly be your actual code, you are returning a string in `Main` that is expecting an `int`.

Comment: There you go, what comes after it doesn't matter on this case. The problem is that for some reason c# is reconverting the string to the original double value if I add the "|" and I don't have a clue how to avoid this.

Comment: The reason we are being so picky is that the code you show here absolutely *cannot* produce the output you claim it does. Therefore, you must be running different code. Show us that code or give us a [mre].

Comment: Then I don't know. This is the code I'm using on the program. I thought exactly the same, that the value i was sending on the string couldn't be modified again, but apparently the "|" is producing this.

Comment: String concatenation, regardless of whether you use `|` or not, will not change the value, therefore this code cannot give you that issue.

Comment: If I remove the "|" from it, then both numbers match every single time.

Comment: Then show us a [mre] that we can copy and paste into our environment and see the same as you, until you do that, we cannot help.

Comment: Can you please share a sreenshot of your code, just to verify that the code you have written here is identical to what you see on the screen? If possible make the screenshot while a breakpoint is hit on the line `return result;` and put `message` and `perfData` into the watch window

Comment: I tested it locally and I cannot reproduce the error. Basically this check is running through NSClient++ on a remote device and maybe NSClient++ is changing the value somehow. I don't know, it does not look to be an issue with C#.

Comment: Because I was testing if for some reason it was being changed in between or not. I'm closing this for now since it does not seem to be an issue with c#.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - well the whole output seems odd, why would there be need to output the connection time twice. I already though about, "Well, if your second output of the same time, makes problem, don't waste time and just simply remove the second output, problem solved!"

Comment: Not sure if it would make any difference but you could try to change `"|"` to `" | "` (with spaces), the output would be more appealing to the eyes aswell.

Comment: Yeah, I cannot do that because of how the output format should look like for Nagios to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm closing this post for now since it does not seem to be an issue with c#. It looks like NSClient++ is changing this value after it is returned.

I'm not sure though, I will post it on the proper section.

Thank you all!.